# unknown compilation error in c++ constructors

Tags: c++

I can't run my project in c++. I got a lot of errors, so I don't know which one error is that real. I'm adding the code and error logs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Restaurant {
    Menu menu;
    static const int NUMBER_TABLES = 10;
    set<int> occupiedTables;
    Table tables[NUMBER_TABLES];

    public: Restaurant() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TABLES; i++) {
            tables[i] = Table();
        }
    }

    public: Table getTable(int number) {
        return tables[number];
        }

    public:bool newCustomer(int tableNumber) {
        if (tableNumber < 1 || tableNumber > NUMBER_TABLES || occupiedTables.find(tableNumber) != occupiedTables.end())
            return false;
        tables[tableNumber].setOccupied(true);
        occupiedTables.insert(tableNumber);
        return true;
    }

    public:bool leaveCustomer(int tableNumber) {
        if (tableNumber < 1 || tableNumber > NUMBER_TABLES || occupiedTables.find(tableNumber) == occupiedTables.end())
            return false;
        tables[tableNumber].setOccupied(false);
        occupiedTables.erase(tableNumber);
        return true;
    }

    public: void addToOrder(int tableNumber, int meal_id, int pieces = 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {
            tables[tableNumber].getOrder().setOrder(meal_id);
        }
    }
};

class Table {
    Order order;
    bool occupied = false;

    public: Order getOrder() {
            return order;
        }

    public: bool isOccupied() {
        return occupied;
        }

    public: bool setOccupied(bool occupied) {
        this->isOccupied = occupied;
    }
};

class FoodDrink{
    int id;
    string name;
    double price;
    int preparationTime;

public: FoodDrink() {};

public: FoodDrink(int id, string name, double price, int preparationTime) {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
        this->price = price;
        this->preparationTime = preparationTime;
    }

public: int getId() {
    return id;
}

public: string getName() {
    return name;
}

public: double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public: int getPreparationTime() {
    return preparationTime;
}

};

class Menu {
    static const int SOUP_NUMBER = 4;
    static const int MAINMEAL_NUMBER = 5;
    static const int SIDEDISH_NUMBER = 3;
    static const int DRINK_NUMBER = 4;
    static const int ALL_MEAL_NUMBER = SOUP_NUMBER + MAINMEAL_NUMBER + SIDEDISH_NUMBER + DRINK_NUMBER;
    FoodDrink allMeals[ALL_MEAL_NUMBER] =
    { FoodDrink(0, "Garlic soup", 1.49, 8), FoodDrink(1, "Vegetable soup", 1.59, 10),
    FoodDrink(2, "Chicken soup", 1.69, 9), FoodDrink(3, "Beef soup", 1.69, 11),
    FoodDrink(4, "Potato dumplings with sheep cheese", 4.95, 16), FoodDrink(5, "Chicken with niva sauce", 6.75, 19),
        FoodDrink(6, "Spicy pork ribs", 7.49, 23), FoodDrink(7, "Beef on mushrooms", 8.25, 22),
        FoodDrink(8, "Vegetable risotto", 4.99, 15), FoodDrink(9, "Chips", 1.79, 7), FoodDrink(10, "Potatos", 1.59, 12),
        FoodDrink(11, "Rice", 1.49, 11), FoodDrink(12, "Beer", 1.79, 2), FoodDrink(13, "Coca-cola", 1.59, 1),
        FoodDrink(14, "Orange juice", 1.99, 1), FoodDrink(15, "Mineral watter", 1.39, 1)
    };

public: FoodDrink getMeal(int id) {
    return allMeals[id];
}



public:void showMenu() {
    cout << "MENU" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "Id" << setw(40) << "Meal/drink" << setw(15) << "Price(eur)" << setw(20) << "Preparation(min)" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Soups" << endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < ALL_MEAL_NUMBER; i++) {
        if (i == SOUP_NUMBER)
            cout << "Main meals" << endl;
        else if (i == SOUP_NUMBER + MAINMEAL_NUMBER)
            cout << "Side dishes" << endl;
        else if (i == SOUP_NUMBER + MAINMEAL_NUMBER + SIDEDISH_NUMBER)
            cout << "Drinks" << endl;
        cout << setw(5) << allMeals[i].getId() << setw(40) << allMeals[i].getName() << setw(13)
            << allMeals[i].getPrice() << setw(12) << allMeals[i].getPreparationTime() << endl;
    }
    }
};

class Order {
    vector<FoodDrink> order;
    bool isPaid = false;
    Menu menu;

    public: void setOrder(int id){
        order.push_back(menu.getMeal(id));
    }


    public: double calculateOrder() {
        double total = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++) {
                total += order[i].getPrice();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public: void pay() {
        isPaid = true;
    }



};

    int main() {
        Menu m;
        Restaurant r;
        r.newCustomer(1);
        r.addToOrder(1, 5);
        r.addToOrder(1, 12, 2);
        cout << r.getTable(1).getOrder().calculateOrder() << endl;
    }
```

And error log:

> 1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(11):
>   error C3646: 'menu': unknown override specifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(11):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(14):
>   error C3646: 'tables': unknown override specifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(14):
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '['
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(14):
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(14):
>   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(22):
>   error C3646: 'getTable': unknown override specifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(22):
>   error C2059: syntax error: '('
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(22):
>   error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
>   function body
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(18):
>   error C2065: 'tables': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(18):
>   error C3861: 'Table': identifier not found
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(29):
>   error C2065: 'tables': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(37):
>   error C2065: 'tables': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(44):
>   error C2065: 'tables': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(50):
>   error C3646: 'order': unknown override specifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(50):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(53):
>   error C3646: 'getOrder': unknown override specifier
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(53):
>   error C2059: syntax error: '('
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(53):
>   error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
>   function body
>   1>c:\users\jmize\source\repos\restauracia\restauracia\source.cpp(62):
>   error C2659: '=': function as left operand 1>Done building project
>   "Restauracia.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: `I got a lot of errors`. So minimize the code. It will help you (and us) to find the bug. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: `don't just copy in your entire program`

Comment: Declare Order first, Menu, then Table, then Restaurant.

Comment: where is menu included??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define types before you use them as data members, and / or declare them before you use pointers or references to them.

Rearrange your definitions into the following order

```
class FoodDrink
class Menu
class Order
class Table
class Restaurant
int main()
```

Note that you don't need multiple `public:` markers in each class, an access descriptor applies until another is found.

Answer (score 1):

Order of class declaration was incorrect. Here is the correct class declaration order. also there was an error in setOccupied function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class FoodDrink{
    int id;
    string name;
    double price;
    int preparationTime;

public: FoodDrink() {};

public: FoodDrink(int id, string name, double price, int preparationTime) {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
        this->price = price;
        this->preparationTime = preparationTime;
    }

public: int getId() {
    return id;
}

public: string getName() {
    return name;
}

public: double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public: int getPreparationTime() {
    return preparationTime;
}

};

class Menu {
    static const int SOUP_NUMBER = 4;
    static const int MAINMEAL_NUMBER = 5;
    static const int SIDEDISH_NUMBER = 3;
    static const int DRINK_NUMBER = 4;
    static const int ALL_MEAL_NUMBER = SOUP_NUMBER + MAINMEAL_NUMBER + SIDEDISH_NUMBER + DRINK_NUMBER;
    FoodDrink allMeals[ALL_MEAL_NUMBER] =
    { FoodDrink(0, "Garlic soup", 1.49, 8), FoodDrink(1, "Vegetable soup", 1.59, 10),
    FoodDrink(2, "Chicken soup", 1.69, 9), FoodDrink(3, "Beef soup", 1.69, 11),
    FoodDrink(4, "Potato dumplings with sheep cheese", 4.95, 16), FoodDrink(5, "Chicken with niva sauce", 6.75, 19),
        FoodDrink(6, "Spicy pork ribs", 7.49, 23), FoodDrink(7, "Beef on mushrooms", 8.25, 22),
        FoodDrink(8, "Vegetable risotto", 4.99, 15), FoodDrink(9, "Chips", 1.79, 7), FoodDrink(10, "Potatos", 1.59, 12),
        FoodDrink(11, "Rice", 1.49, 11), FoodDrink(12, "Beer", 1.79, 2), FoodDrink(13, "Coca-cola", 1.59, 1),
        FoodDrink(14, "Orange juice", 1.99, 1), FoodDrink(15, "Mineral watter", 1.39, 1)
    };

public: FoodDrink getMeal(int id) {
    return allMeals[id];
}



public:void showMenu() {
    cout << "MENU" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "Id" << setw(40) << "Meal/drink" << setw(15) << "Price(eur)" << setw(20) << "Preparation(min)" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Soups" << endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < ALL_MEAL_NUMBER; i++) {
        if (i == SOUP_NUMBER)
            cout << "Main meals" << endl;
        else if (i == SOUP_NUMBER + MAINMEAL_NUMBER)
            cout << "Side dishes" << endl;
        else if (i == SOUP_NUMBER + MAINMEAL_NUMBER + SIDEDISH_NUMBER)
            cout << "Drinks" << endl;
        cout << setw(5) << allMeals[i].getId() << setw(40) << allMeals[i].getName() << setw(13)
            << allMeals[i].getPrice() << setw(12) << allMeals[i].getPreparationTime() << endl;
    }
    }
};

class Order {
    vector<FoodDrink> order;
    bool isPaid = false;
    Menu menu;

    public: void setOrder(int id){
        order.push_back(menu.getMeal(id));
    }


    public: double calculateOrder() {
        double total = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < order.size(); i++) {
                total += order[i].getPrice();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public: void pay() {
        isPaid = true;
    }



};

class Table {
    Order order;
    bool occupied = false;

    public: Order getOrder() {
            return order;
        }

    public: bool isOccupied() {
        return occupied;
        }

    public: bool setOccupied(bool occupied) {
        this->occupied = true;
    }
};

class Restaurant {
    Menu menu;
    static const int NUMBER_TABLES = 10;
    set<int> occupiedTables;
    Table tables[NUMBER_TABLES];

    public: Restaurant() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TABLES; i++) {
            tables[i] = Table();
        }
    }

    public: Table getTable(int number) {
        return tables[number];
        }

    public:bool newCustomer(int tableNumber) {
        if (tableNumber < 1 || tableNumber > NUMBER_TABLES || occupiedTables.find(tableNumber) != occupiedTables.end())
            return false;
        tables[tableNumber].setOccupied(true);
        occupiedTables.insert(tableNumber);
        return true;
    }

    public:bool leaveCustomer(int tableNumber) {
        if (tableNumber < 1 || tableNumber > NUMBER_TABLES || occupiedTables.find(tableNumber) == occupiedTables.end())
            return false;
        tables[tableNumber].setOccupied(false);
        occupiedTables.erase(tableNumber);
        return true;
    }

    public: void addToOrder(int tableNumber, int meal_id, int pieces = 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {
            tables[tableNumber].getOrder().setOrder(meal_id);
        }
    }
};

    int main() {
        Menu m;
        Restaurant r;
        r.newCustomer(1);
        r.addToOrder(1, 5);
        r.addToOrder(1, 12, 2);
        cout << r.getTable(1).getOrder().calculateOrder() << endl;
    }
```